# Why I am getting the Typerror cannot read property map of undefined, despite the my transaction state object is updating dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, map-function

[Updated CodeSandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-albattani-qub76?file=/src/TransactionList.js)
[image: Map function property undefined]

The Add transaction button is not rendering the transaction list in transaction history container
This piece of code `{transaction && transaction.map(trans)....` is rendering the app UI but the Add transaction button is not generating the Transaction component dynamically in transaction history container}

[image: The expense tracker app transaction history is not rendering the list after adding the transaction.]

[image: transaction state object in dev tools]

```
 import React from 'react';

const AddTransaction = 
({item,amount,setItem,setAmount,transaction,setTransaction}) 
=> {


const onSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
setTransaction([...transaction,
                
    {
        text: item,
        amount: amount,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
    }

    ] );

setItem('');
setAmount('');
}

return (
    <div   className='addtransaction-container'>
  
    <div className='add-trans-header'>

        <h4>Add New Transaction</h4>

    </div>

    <form>

    <div className="form-control">

    <label htmlFor="text">Text</label>

    <input type="text" value={item} 
    onChange={(e) => setItem(e.target.value)} 
    placeholder="Enter text..." />

    </div>

    <div className="form-control">

    <label htmlFor="amount"

    >Amount <br />

    (negative - expense, positive - income)
    
    </label>

    <input type="number" value={amount} 
    onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)} 
    placeholder="Enter amount..." />

    </div>

    <button type='button' onClick={onSubmit} 
            value='submit'
            className="btn">
            Add transaction
    </button>

    </form>

    </div>
    );
  }

  export default AddTransaction;
```

The map function is not rendering the  `Transaction`
component in `TransactionList.js` file

```
  import React from 'react'
  import './App.css';
  import Transaction from './Transaction.js';

  const TransactionList = ({text,transaction,amount}) => {


  return (


  <div className='transactionlist-container'>

    <div className='transactionlist-header-container'>

    <h4>

     Transaction History

    </h4>
    
    </div>

    <ul>
           <li>
    
            { transaction.map(trans => 
            
               <Transaction
                amount={transaction.amount}
                text={transaction.text}
                key={transaction.id} />

            )}
        </li>

        </ul>

    
    
    
      </div>
      )
      }

     export default TransactionList;
```

My `Transaction.js` file have a ul list with the input text and amount but the component is not rendering in the app UI.

```
import React from 'react'

const Transaction = ({transaction,text,amount}) => {
return (
    <div className='transaction'>
        {text}<span>{amount}</span>
    </div>
    )
 }

 export default Transaction;
```

Comment: You've showed us where you update the transaction state, but can you show us where you create it in the first place?

Comment: App.js const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState([]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated the app, which is working without any issue.

Here is the link to the working demo: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ywiq7h?file=src%2FApp.js)

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TransactionList from "./TransactionList";
import AddTransaction from "./AddTransaction";

const App = () => {
  const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState([]);

  const handleTransaction = value => {
    setTransaction([...transaction, value]);
  };
  const expenseList = transaction.filter(trans => Number(trans.amount) < 0);
  const expense = expenseList.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc + Number(curr.amount),
    0
  );

  const amountList = transaction.filter(trans => Number(trans.amount) > 0);
  const amount = amountList.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + Number(curr.amount), 0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("From app:", transaction);
  }, [transaction]);

  return (
    <div className="transactionlist-container">
      <div>
        <span>income: {JSON.stringify(amount)}</span>{" "}
        <span> total expense: {JSON.stringify(expense)}</span>
        <span> balance: {amount + expense}</span>
      </div>
      <TransactionList transaction={transaction} />
      <AddTransaction
        transaction={transaction}
        handleTransaction={handleTransaction}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import Transaction from "./Transaction";

const TransactionList = ({ transaction }) => {
  console.log("from tl:", transaction);
  return (
    <div className="transactionlist-container">
      <div className="transactionlist-header-container">
        <h4>Transaction History</h4>
      </div>

      {transaction.map(trans => (
        <Transaction amount={trans.amount} text={trans.text} key={trans.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TransactionList;
```

```
import React from "react";

const Transaction = ({ text, amount }) => {
  return (
    <div className="transaction">
      {text}
      <span>{amount}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Transaction;
```

```
import React,{useState} from "react"
const AddTransaction = 
({handleTransaction}) 
=> {
  const [item,setItem] = useState("")
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0)
const onSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
handleTransaction(     
    {
        text: item,
        amount: amount,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
    }

   );

setItem('');
setAmount('');
}

return (
     <div
        className="inputBox"
      >
  
    <div className='add-trans-header'>

        <h4>Add New Transaction</h4>

    </div>

    <form>

    <div className="form-control">

    <label htmlFor="text">Text</label>

    <input type="text" value={item} 
    onChange={(e) => setItem(e.target.value)} 
    placeholder="Enter text..." />

    </div>

    <div className="form-control">

    <label htmlFor="amount"

    >Amount <br />

    (negative - expense, positive - income)
    
    </label>

    <input type="number" value={amount} 
    onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)} 
    placeholder="Enter amount..." />

    </div>

    <button type='button' onClick={onSubmit} 
            value='submit'
            className="btn">
            Add transaction
    </button>

    </form>

    </div>
    );
  }

  export default AddTransaction;
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort........but I want to know what's wrong with my code, why it is not rendering the list in UI?

Comment: check the code of ```TransactionList``` , you were passing the text and amount incorrectly.

Comment: also, the CodeSandbox link provided in question is missing some code, because of that I had to create an entire app on my own.

Comment: Yes, but i was trying to build it without contextApi